# How to return ArrayList from Coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

How to return `ArrayList` from `Coroutine`?

```
    GlobalScope.launch {
       val list = retrieveData(firstDateOfMonth,lastDateOfMonth)
      }

 suspend fun retrieveData(
        first: Date,
        last: Date,
 ): ArrayList<Readings> = suspendCoroutine { c ->

        var sensorReadingsList : ArrayList<Readings>?=null

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val task2 = async {
                WebApi.ReadingsList(
                    activity,auth_token, first, last
                )
            }
            val resp2 = task2.await()

            if (resp2?.status == "Success") {
                 sensorReadingsList = resp2?.organization_sensor_readings
            }

            c.resume(sensorReadingsList)
        }
    }
```

**Error**

> Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter T in inline fun 
>   Continuation.resume(value: T): Unit None of the following
>   substitutions receiver:
>   Continuation? /* =
>   java.util.ArrayList? */>  arguments:
>   (kotlin.collections.ArrayList? /* =
>   java.util.ArrayList? */)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `WebApi.ReadingsList` is a non-suspending function.  That means that you'll need to make a thread wait while it runs.  You probably don't want to use `Dispatchers.Main` for that, since that would run it on the UI thread.  `Dispatchers.IO` would be the normal choice.

You also really shouldn't call `suspendCoroutine` for this.  That's meant for low-level interoperation with other kinds of async callbacks, which you don't have in this case.  Something like this would be more appropriate:

```
suspend fun retrieveData(
        first: Date,
        last: Date,
 ): ArrayList<Readings>? {
    val resp2 = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            WebApi.ReadingsList(activity,auth_token, first, last)
        }
    if (resp2?.status == "Success") {
        return resp2?.organization_sensor_readings
    } 
    return null
}
```

This will run the blocking call in a subordinate job on an IO thread.  This ensures that if your coroutine is cancelled, then the subordinate job will be cancelled too -- although that won't interrupt the blocking call.